# as3 totalFrames return 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frames

I am trying to load one animation.
I want to know the end of the animation and avoid it in a loop.

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader( );
var myLoaderReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("anim.swf");
myLoader.load(myLoaderReq);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , enterFrameListener );
addChild(myLoader);

myLoader.x = 10;
myLoader.y = 20;


function enterFrameListener(event:Event):void
{
  var mc:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;

  trace(mc.currentFrame);
  if( mc.currentFrame == mc.totalFrames )
  {
      mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , enterFrameListener );
      trace("end of movie reached");
  }
}
```

for test i uses swf downloaded from http://www.leconcombre.com/movies/movies1us.html

any ideas how to do that?

thnx

Comment: `mc` in your enterFrameListener will refer to the scope of the code you posted.   What you want to check is the currentFrame and totalFrames of your loaded movie clip which is probably `myLoader.content.totalFrames`

Comment: ya its correct. When i tried myLoder.content.totalframes its grreater than 25, thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currentTarget you are using is refer to

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , enterFrameListener );
```

Which should be your MainTimeline, if you add one more frame then should be return 2 of totalFrames.

As BadFeelingAboutThis saids, just replace:

```
var mc:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;
```

by

```
var mc:MovieClip = myLoader.content as MovieClip;
```

You also have to confirm you are attempting to manipulate the MainTimeline of anim.swf.